# My .js files don't work, get's saved as a textfile and not as a javascript file

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3

I have a problem with my javascript files, when I save a file with .js it don't work as a javascript file but more like a pain text file.

The only file I have managed to work is if i name my file test.js then it works.

You can see my problem on the uploaded images.

I use Sublime Test.

Works here:
[image: works here]

Doesn't work here:
[image: don't work here]

Comment: Hi! Your problem is quite weird. I also use Sublime Text and if you save a file with `.js` extension, it'll be highlighted following the Javascript rules. I would remove it from the computer and install it again, checking that the process finishes fine. Also, make sure you have the latest version (right now is 3.2.2 build 3211). Cheers,

Comment: i am using 3.2.2 and uninstall don't work still the same. :(

Answer (score 0):

Update your sublime text, I got issues related to that when using sublime text in the past.
You can also use another editor to name your file and file extension and then open it up in sublime text. This is sure to work.

Comment: Also try to correct the markdown for the images as they do not display

Comment: Try the second option listed above { use notepad++ or notepad }

Comment: I've just tried with atom and it works! Thank you, but it could stil be cool if sublime could work since I have paid for it....